# bash: read from input files and perform calculations and write errors to log file

Tags: bash, file

I have got two text files as below. Which consists of each items quantity, price, total and all items Total at the end of each file.

> `file1.txt`
>
> ```
> Date: 05-10-2016
> Item1 5 1000 6000
> Item2 7 1500 10500
> Item3 4 2000 8000
> Total: 24500
> ```

.

> `file2.txt`
>
> ```
> Date: 07-12-2016
> Item1 7 750 5250
> Item2 3 900 2700
> Item3 8 1000 9000
> Total: 16950
> ```

I am trying to read through each file and total again by adding individual item prices present in the file. When the total does not match, it should write an error message in the `error.txt` file clearly stating which days data had the problem.

> `error.txt`
>
> ```
> Date: 05-10-2016
> Item1 5 1000 6000 : Item total calculation is wrong.
> Total: 24500 : All items total calculation is wrong.
>
> Date: 07-12-2016
> Item3 8 1000 9000 : Item total calculation is wrong.
> Total: 16950 : All items total calculation is wrong.
> ```

Comment: for f in *.txt; do    
   awk 'NR>1{ a[$1]=$2*$3 }{ print }END{ printf("\n"); 
        for(i in f)
        {  print i,"Error in calculations",a[i] } 
        }' "$f" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$f"; 
done

Comment: Please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, such as the code that you have tried, please update your question by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/204869) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/Date/{d=$0;t=0;p=0;next;}
     /Total/{if(t!=int($2)){if(p==0){print d; p=1;}; print $0,":","All items total calculation is wrong."};next;} 
     {k=int($2)*int($3);t+=k;if(k!=int($4)){if(p==0){print d; p=1;}; print $0,":","Item total calculation is wrong."}}' file1 file2 >error.txt
```

output:

```
cat error.txt

Date: 05-10-2016
Item1 5 1000 6000 : Item total calculation is wrong.
Total: 24500 : All items total calculation is wrong.
Date: 07-12-2016
Item3 8 1000 9000 : Item total calculation is wrong.
Total: 16950 : All items total calculation is wrong.
```